# Media Queries - swapping images for different devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

I'm new to coding and I've been trying to figure out how to change certain elements in a WordPress theme, one of which is to show a  full LinkedIn image on a desktop but on mobile devices it switches to the shorter logo [IN].

I've got it to work thanks to reading a few articles on StackOverflow however the fix has made the call to action drop down under the Linkedin logo. I'm sure this is a real newbie mistake and I'm completely missing something but I can't for the life of me get the call to action back up next to the Linkedin logo, both on Desktop and on Mobile. (I have a feeling it might be something to do with the surrounding div however I can't see anything with a width that I can change in Chrome Inspect to make it pop back up next to the logo).

Heres to the code:

```
HTML

<a href="www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">
<div class="exampleimage"></div></a>
<a href="tel:123 456 789">Need Help? Call » 123 456 789</a>



CSS
.exampleimage{
   background-image: url("http://testenvironment-wel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Working-Environments-Company-LinkedIn-Logo.png");
   background-size: contain;
   width: 140px;
   height: 18px; 

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){

   .exampleimage{
       background-image: url("http://testenvironment-wel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Working-Environments-LinkedIn-Logo-small-version.png");
    background-size: cover;
         width: 22px;
     height: 18px;
   }
}
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HVqb.jpg)

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

:)

Comment: put link to real image and not relative links so we can test your code

Comment: I've added the path in now

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the .jpeg is missing in your media query?

```
   background-image: url("Linkedinlogo2.jpg");
```

Comment: no the image shows i've just edited the file path to put it on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go with mobile first.
Remember that u din't add file type on the mobile background-image (.jpg/.jpeg), that's the main reason it din't work.

```
CSS
.exampleimage{
  background-image: url("Linkedinlogo2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 22px;
  height: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px){
  .exampleimage{
    background-image: url("Linkedinlogo1.jpeg");
    background-size: contain;
    width: 140px;
    height: 18px;
  }
}
```

Comment: i've edited the file path in the text box on stackoverflow. so that isn't the issue.